# I am having trouble making python dictionary or list

Tags: python

I am very new to python and have a script that i wrote in PowerShell that I would like to recreate in python.

in powershell i have created a hashtable:

```
   $epBody = @{
                    "escalation_policy"   = @{
                        "type"               =   "escalation_policy"
                        "name"               =   $epName
                        "escalation_rules"   = @(
                            @{
                                "escalation_delay_in_minutes" = 30
                                "targets"                     = @(
                                    @{
                                        "id"    = $userid
                                        "type"  = "user_reference"
                                    }
                                )
                            }
                        ) 
                    }
                }
```

And trying to figure out the best way to write this in python.

this is what i have (which i know is wrong!):

```
ep_payload = {
                "escalation_policy": {
                        "type": "escalation_policy",
                        "name": epName,
                        "escalation_rules": [
                            {
                                "escalation_delay_in_minutes": 30,
                                "targets": [
                                    {
                                        "id": userid
                                        "type": "user_reference"
                                    }
                        ]
                            }
                        ] 
                    }
                }
```

I just cannot figure out the correct syntax for this one

cheers,

Comment: You need a comma after `userid`.

Comment: "this is what i have (which i know is wrong!):" Well, *how do you know* it's wrong? Did you get an error message? If you got an error message: what kind of error does it say there was? Do you see the `^` in the error message? Where is it pointing? Hint: where the code says `"name": epName,`, that is *correct*. Why does it *not* incorrectly say `"name": epName` instead? Now, look carefully where it says `"id": userid`. Do you see how the same logic applies? Please also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: thanks guys, VS Code was showing errors everywhere and i was staring at it for ages last night. I had a feeling it would be something silly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Let's eat Grandma",  "Lets eat, Grandma"  Commas save lives!

Comment: lol yes thanks :)